# How Vulkan application find the address of the function in driver

Tags: nvidia, vulkan, amd-gpu

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am studying Vulkan driver code. I want to know how the application call the driver func because the func name is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then look at Vulkan Loader [trampoline](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/bf28c824b820eda6ea3286b301329d59686c4149/loader/trampoline.c). Which in turn will hit the driver per [LoaderDriverInterface.md](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/bf28c824b820eda6ea3286b301329d59686c4149/docs/LoaderDriverInterface.md) documentation.